# Configuration react-router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, frontend

I have two pages, admin and login page. If user not logged admin page must redirect to login page, and if user logged login page must redirect to admin page.

In react-router v3 I have onEnter and onChange methods, In this methods I can get store and look if user logged or not and `replace` route, but In v4 dont exist this methods, so all logic which contain onEnter and onChange methods I must put in component, for example, in `componentWillReceiveProps` ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In react-router v4, Routes are considered as just another type of components. A Route simply a component that renders the another given component if browser location matches the given path and that's all it does. Because of this design decision, it doesn't make much sense to have another set of lifecycle methods specifically for Routes and we can leverage React component lifecycle methods instead. In my experience, it almost covers all the use cases which are supported by react-router v3 lifecycle hooks.

In your case, you can simply put conditional [`<Redirect/>`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) tag in your JSX of admin component and login component to make it work. Also, this scenario has been nicely explained in new react-router 4 [docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow).